# UWP Entity Framework with SQLite using Prepopulated Data

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sqlite, uwp

I have a couple of XML files in my project full of data, roughly about 10.4MB worth of XML. Loading it in UWP works but it's a bit slow. I'd like to go with a SQLite DB for performance, because I only need to search parts of my XML data at a time and so I don't need to load up the entire XML all at once.

The docs pointed to here don't include any information about how to use a prepopulated database. They assume that you'll do a migration, create a db, and start loading data at runtime, which is fine for most cases but not for my specific needs.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/data-access/entity-framework-7-with-sqlite-for-csharp-apps

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/uwp/getting-started

If I transpose all of my XML over to SQLite on a first run, it'll be a bit slow, I'd like to just have it all prepopulated and ready to go from SQLite on the first run. What's a good way to achieve this?

It looks like my .db that had its schema created through EF but has no data in it yet is sitting in AppData\Local\Package\MyApp\LocalState, I'd like to take that file, load it up with data, and then load it into the project (preferably in my Assets directory as a Content build type). Is this a feasible solution?

EDIT: This is different from the provided solution because as per the article I provided I'm using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite rather than SQLite.Net-PCL, so I'll need to know how to properly reference the dataset, preferably in a read/write location, and pass that into DbContext's OnConfiguring method I presume.

Comment: Looks like that solution is using SQLite.NET and I'm using Entity Framework Core, are these solutions compatible? Looks like I can bring in the db as a Content build type just fine, but I'll need a way to reference the path and load it in at runtime. So I'll need to be able to get the right path and load it into DbContext's OnConfiguring method.

Comment: Just a note for anyone coming through, I resolved the issue by using a mix of EF Core for persistent data and System.Data.SQLite (NuGet package) for SQLite data that I read in via Views since EF Core doesn't support Views yet and it's slow with relational data, even with explicit loading. It's similar to the method described in the above post, but the namespaces are different, and it looks like it's not PCL.